# Automating the download of a file

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding automating the download of a file via the web-browser in c#.

Pretty much this code right here;

```
try
{
    HtmlElement downloadlink = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dl_link").All[0];
    webBrowser1.Navigate(downloadlink.GetAttribute("href"));

    textBox1.Clear();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("The YouTube URL is incorrect. Please try a different YouTube URL.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    textBox1.Clear();
}
```

is what activates the download of the file I want. Pretty much, the box of where you want to save pops up, and I would simply want to automate it and make it download into a folder I have under the c:\ drive.

I looked over numerous amounts of code which made the coder input the link (URL) of the file download, but for my case the link (URL) is not technically given, so I was wondering how I would approach this situation and would it be possible to automate it?

Comment: Are you trying to download youtube videos?

Comment: Instead of editing your question to say that you fixed the problem (and removing all other content), try leaving a comment, or better yet, write your own answer and accept it. That way this question may help other people as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have the URL: `downloadlink.GetAttribute("href")`, you could pass that to `WebCilent.DownloadData(string url)`, or is that not the case?